# Docusign - sandbox - Redirect URI - not working

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying out Docusign sandbox environment in which I have created an integrator key with appropriate `redirect uri`

When I request the api:
`https://admindemo.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=id_token&scope=open_id&client_id=<integrator-key>&state=custom&redirect_uri=https://webhook.site/1b7aba4c-f96f-41e1-922d-2d8d38392208&admin_consent_scope=impersonation`

Docusign does not redirect to the redirect-url, but opens the Docusign admin page.

If I request the URL:
`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=id_token&scope=open_id&client_id=<integrator-key>&state=custom&redirect_uri=https://webhook.site/1b7aba4c-f96f-41e1-922d-2d8d38392208&admin_consent_scope=impersonation`

Then I get the error:

`You are not an organization admin. Please contact your DocuSign Administrator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response_type=id_token` is invalid. The response type should be `code`. Unfortunately, the 'Obtaining Consent' documentation still references this incorrect value.

`scope=open_id` can only be used if your account is associated with an Organization, and if you are an Organization Administrator. If your account is not under an Organization, you'll need to use the individual consent workflow, which means `scope` should be `signature impersonation` and the `admin_consent_scope` parameter should be removed.

If you would like to create an Organization in the sandbox environment, you will need to open a case with DocuSign Support requesting that functionality be added to your Demo account. To have that enabled in Production, you'll need to contact your Account Manager or the Sales team.

Comment: Hi it would be very helpful if you could add these details to the documentation, otherwise it takes a lot of time for someone to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear -- please update your question if this answer is in the wrong direction.

I think you are trying to implement the oauth authorization code grant flow and are having a problem.

The starting url for DocuSign for the oauth auth code grant flow:

- For the developer sandbox environment: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth
- For the production platforms: https://account.docusign.com/oauth/auth

Also, why are you including the `admin_consent_scope` query parameter?

Hopefully this answer regarding the correct url will help. If so, then ask a NEW question if you run into any future issues.

[Developer documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant)